# Must declare the scalar variable "@ASIN"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

I dont understand the error message. What does it mead by scalar variable? @ASIN value should be stored in the id variable I created for the GetByAsin method.

```
//Gets one Music Detail
public MusicDescriptionModel GetByAsin(string id)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = connection)
    {
        string sql = "select ASIN, Title, Artist, Price, ReleaseDate,NumberDisks,label,DetailPageURL, Review" +
            "FROM tblDescription WHERE id = @ASIN";
        //need to parameterize ID to avoid sql injection attacks.
        MusicDescriptionModel musicdesc = db.Query<MusicDescriptionModel>(sql, new { id }).SingleOrDefault();
        return musicdesc;
    }
}
```

Comment: how is @ASIN getting set in your sql string?

Comment: it is in id = @ASIN

Comment: @mason beat me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't passed a variable for Dapper to bind to @ASIN. Try:

```
MusicDescriptionModel musicdesc
  = db.Query<MusicDescriptionModel>(sql, new { ASIN = id }).SingleOrDefault();
```

or try:

```
 string sql = "select ASIN, Title, Artist, Price, ReleaseDate,NumberDisks,label,DetailPageURL, Review" +  
                       "FROM tblDescription WHERE id = @Id";
```

You can't use a different name and expect it to magically line them up for you. They need to match.

Comment: I tried it, but it is giving me an error message saying id is an invalid column

Comment: @TimothyWong Well then look at `tblDescription` and see what column you should be filtering on. I don't have access to your database to see what columns are defined on your tables.

Comment: I am trying to make the string id that I want to pass in equal to ASIN. That is why is put id = @ASIN in my where statement. The problem is:       MusicDescriptionModel musicdesc = db.Query<MusicDescriptionModel>(sql, new { id }).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: @TimothyWong Try running the query in SSMS or SQCMD. Does it not work there? Then it won't work with Dapper either. You can't use a column if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = "select ASIN, Title, Artist, Price, ReleaseDate,NumberDisks,label,DetailPageURL, Review" +  
                       "FROM tblDescription WHERE ASIN = @ASINSqlParam";
        //need to parameterize ID to avoid sql injection attacks.
        MusicDescriptionModel musicdesc = db.Query<MusicDescriptionModel>(sql, new { ASINSqlParam = id }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Should do the trick.

Docs [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#parameterized-queries) may help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my where statement
I need to make the scalar variable @id
WHERE ASIN = @id